# Image from images folder is not loading in mobilefirst

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst

i am working with mobilefirst project.

I am facing an issue of not able to load an image in javascript. My image is placed inside a images folder. when i check the console  is added inside the div and tool tip over that **src**tells **Could not load the image**.

```
jQuery('#placeher').show();
          //  var table = $('#mydemo1');

            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
            {
                doc1=result[i];
                if(doc1.PHOTO == "")
                {       
                    var elem = document.createElement("img");
                    elem.setAttribute("src","../common/images/Icon-60.png");
                    elem.setAttribute("height", "60");
                    elem.setAttribute("width", "60");
                    document.getElementById("placeher").appendChild(elem);       
                }               
            }
```

Comment: Your code will not know what is "common" - that folder is not present in the generated app; use just "images". BTW, you can also preview the app in Chrome and then debug it using the Chrome devtools -> Console. You will then see the error that is produced.

Comment: yep i know i have tried that also  removed common                elem.setAttribute("src","../images/Icon-60.png");

Comment: That's a local address to your computer... it will obviously not load here.

Comment: cant understand i have followed similarly for all app buttons icon same way in css by having the images in images folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct path to use for the images folder is simply `images/<image file name>`. For example: `<img src="images/thumbnail.png"/>`.